# xhtml text field with long label hidden inside

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, label

So I've got a search box with a long label inside, for example:

"Name, lastname, PersonCode, and so on... "

And the text field is too small to fit it all.

I need to make the full label visible, when I move the mouse over it.

The code I'm using for the text field is:

```
<p:outputPanel id="keywords_filter" rendered="#{!externalRegistryQueryController.filter.detailedFilter}">
    <p:inputText value="#{externalRegistryQueryController.filter.keywords}" placeholder="#{msg.extreg_keywords_placeholder}"/>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: In addition to the `title` attribute, PrimeFaces has its own component [`<p:tooltip>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `title` attribute:

```
<p:inputText
        value="#{externalRegistryQueryController.filter.keywords}"
        placeholder="#{msg.extreg_keywords_placeholder}"
        title="#{msg.extreg_keywords_placeholder}"/>
```

The `title` attribute is defined on the PrimeFaces `inputText` element, and is mapped to the HTML `title` attribute, which gives you to the tooltip behavior that you're requesting.

Comment: Lol.. Now I am ashamed I needed post it here when answer is so simple..

It's works, thank you. !